# put a laravel 9 project online on OVH using filezilla

Tags: laravel-9, ovh

I made a Laravel 9 project with a mysql database and I try to put it online with the OVH as host.
I used FileZilla to:

1. I checked the version of php in "composer.json" and updated on OVH to be the same.
2. I copied my project in the "www" directory (no failed tranfert)
3. I moved the contain of the public directory to be in the same place than the project file.
4. I updated my index.php by delete everything and adding the following code:

```
<?php 
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require__DIR__.'/ADA2023/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once__DIR__.'/ADA2023/bootstrap/app.php';
?>
```

"ADA2023" is the name of the project
And after that I saved but when I tried to access my project online with the name of my domain "https://adatfejogendarme2022.be/" I have the HTTP ERROR 500

I saw another question([How to deploy laravel project on ovh hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038108/how-to-deploy-laravel-project-on-ovh-hosting)) where it's adviced to put the project directory not in the "www" directory
I had try this but it's still showing the same error